# FileSystemWatcher on folder on desktop (or C drive)

Tags: c#, winforms, filesystemwatcher, drive

I am creating a winforms project which checks files in folder. It only works when new file put in the folder. I am using FileSystemWatcher. It works fine on D drive but fails on C drive.

1. I gave EVERYONE full privilige on that folder
2. I tried publishing it with click once for full trust application. But it failed also with published edition
3. Tried to run exe file and visual studio as administrator. Nothing changed
4. Tried absolute path and Extra filters.

It does not raise any errors. Simply does nothing.

**Non Working Code**

```
string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
teklifwatcher.Path = desktop+"\\XMLTeklif";
                    teklifwatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
                    teklifwatcher.Filter = "*.xml";              
                    teklifwatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(TeklifXML);
                    teklifwatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

         private void TeklifXML(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
                {
        //dostuff
        }
```

Comment: In the new versions of Windows, you need administrator privileges to monitor, create and delete files stored on a Windows partition. Have you tried running this application as an administrator?

Comment: I forgot to write that thanks!. Yep I tried @m.rogalski

Comment: Write the exact full path of the directory. Use `NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size` not only `LastWrite`. If you run as administrator, then local folders like `desktop` may be different than current user. Try absolute path like `C:\Test`.

Comment: Dahico please don't embed the answer inside the question. Instead, write a complete answer with the solution, and accept it as the correct one! It's more useful for the other users. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus Sure. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem on my own. I assume filesystemwatcher can't watch c: drive files directly. Because of the security reasons. 
But we can use  Program Files (X86) folders just like any other application.

***Anyone who have similar problems just use filesystemwatcher on a folder at  program filex(x86). And give permissions to that folder. Voila! It works***

Comment: `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)` have unique issues as well.  Instead, consider `Program Data`.

Comment: Program Files(X86) works well for now(with permissions) but I will consider ProgramData next time. Thanks

Comment: @Dahico you mean the whole ProgramFiles(x86) folder ? I tried granting access to my specific folder inside and it did'nt work

Comment: @HariHaran sorry for a very long delay. In that specific case I gave permission for all of the folder. I assume if you only give access to specific folder system folder settings override it